# Content Security Policy errors which I can't declare

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

I created this CSP:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "
default-src 'self'; 
script-src 'report-sample' 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js; 
style-src 'report-sample' 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net https://fonts.googleapis.com https://p.typekit.net https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com https://use.typekit.net; 
object-src 'none'; 
base-uri 'self'; 
connect-src 'self' wss://s-usc1c-nss-208.firebaseio.com; 
font-src 'self' 
data: https://fonts.gstatic.com https://use.typekit.net; 
frame-src 'self' https://www.google.com; 
img-src 'self' data: https://secure.gravatar.com; 
manifest-src 'self'; 
media-src 'self'; 
worker-src 'none';
";
```

Created this one with checking my `console` errors.
But in `script-src` I need to add `unsafe-inline` and `unsafe-eval` to make it works according to the console. But I read a lot that it is not that good solution.
How can I maybe fix it in an other way?

Also I still get `Refused to load the image '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive`

It says images like `data:image/svg....`

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Managed the `data:image/svg` problem with adding `data:` to the `img-src`. But still has the problem with the `unsafe-inline` and `unsafe-eval` in `script-src`

Comment: Well then you will have to find and remove or re-write the parts, that are considered `unsafe-inline` or `unsafe-eval` …

Comment: But the inline parts are from `self` or am I guessing that wrong?

Comment: `'self'` just means sources from your own URL, which is different from sources from within the HTML page itself. The whole point of CSP is that you fix your site to be safe.